# Workbox precache not working: d is not iterable

Tags: workbox

I'm implementing PWA by Workbox(v6.3.0), but I met an issue about precaching.

```js
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

precacheAndRoute([
  { url: '/en/404.html', revision: null }
]);
```

The code was built(Webpack without using any Workbox plugins) successfully, but got error from the console:

```
service-worker.min.f733a2e86a4c8166cd5ccfee2066830592964327bd9886b610c23f45d7861e24.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: d is not iterable
    at t.addToCacheList (service-worker.min.f733a2e86a4c8166cd5ccfee2066830592964327bd9886b610c23f45d7861e24.js:1)
    at t.precache (service-worker.min.f733a2e86a4c8166cd5ccfee2066830592964327bd9886b610c23f45d7861e24.js:1)
    at service-worker.min.f733a2e86a4c8166cd5ccfee2066830592964327bd9886b610c23f45d7861e24.js:1
    at service-worker.min.f733a2e86a4c8166cd5ccfee2066830592964327bd9886b610c23f45d7861e24.js:1
    at service-worker.min.f733a2e86a4c8166cd5ccfee2066830592964327bd9886b610c23f45d7861e24.js:1
    at service-worker.min.f733a2e86a4c8166cd5ccfee2066830592964327bd9886b610c23f45d7861e24.js:1
```

```js
(function(a) {
    l().precache(a)
}
)([{
    url: "/en/404.html",
    revision: null
}]),
```

I'm new to PWA and Workbox, I have not clue to solve the issue.

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug triggered by your code minification. Could you post more details at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues including a link to a live reproduction, or at least the full contents of your service worker file, if possible?

Comment: @JeffPosnick It seems an issue of [Hugo asset minification](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/minification/), I replace it with webpack minification, and then it works as expected. Thanks a lot.